# Service to underline plain text with a line of dashes

Tags: applescript, script, automation, text, services

I am looking for a text service that I can call from a plain text editor (BBedit for example) and will operate the following modification:

Before:

```
This is a line of text
```

After:

```
This is a line of text
----------------------
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BBedit can execute shell commands on selected text, so adapting something like

```
echo 'This is a line of text' | sed -n 'p;s/./-/gp'
```

to make it work when called from BBedit should work.

- `sed -n` runs sed without echoing its input automatically
- `p` is the first command applied to the input, it just prints the input (technically the content of the pattern space)
- `s/./-/gp` is the second command, it replaces all characters in the pattern space by `-` and prints the result

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future readers here is my setup. Based on @nohillside 's answer I used `Automator` to create a service that runs the (bash) shell script:

```
sed -n 'p;s/./-/gp'
```

That makes it easy to add a keyboard shortcut that can be accessed from text editors. Here it is:

[image]